# Compare the objects of NSMutablearray with For loop values

Tags: iphone, ios, for-loop, nsmutablearray

I have the NSMutableArray with following values:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];
```

This is my For loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
{
    //here I want to compare each object from above array with value of i from for loop. and add the further output. e.g.
    if(i== object from array)
    {
          //do this
    }
}
```

Actually I have just five objects or values in array so how can I compare each value of i with each object or values of NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you trust IOS functions `containsObject` and  `indexOfObject`,  then:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];

for(int i = 0; i< 30; i++)
{
    if([array containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i]])
    {
        //array contains  "i" item,  
        //and we can know it's location this way:
        int foundArrayItemId = [array indexOfObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution, but this will only work with simple object like, string and numbers. Not with more complex object.

Comment: Can You provide an example of more complex object? I'm using this method in my own project to check in array and find location of NSIndexPath objects, various string and float values.

Comment: Wel complex object could be object you created your self. Like a class that extents `NSObject` with custom properties. The contains object method will call the `isEqual:` method on the objects in the array: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual:

Comment: Fair enough - then my example would fail. But anyways - I believe we should use simple methods for simple things, and more complex, for complex ones.

Comment: Totally agree, never make you code more complex and it needs to be.

Comment: Would this work if the array contained 5 key/value pair dictionaries as its objects…?

Answer (score 3):

So if I understand you correctly you want to compare each object in the array with all other objects in the Array? Here is example, not test and might need some optimalisation.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];

for(NSInteger i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    for(NSInteger j = 0; j < [array count]; j++) {
        if ( i == j) {
           // No need to check if its the same object.
           continue;
        }

        NSString *stringI = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *stringJ = [array objectAtIndex:j];

        if ([stringI isEqualToString:stringJ) {
           // Do something.
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just use nested loop for comparison like

```
for(i = 0; i <= [array count];i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=[mutableArrya count]; j++)
            {
                 //Do comparison
            }
    }
```

i think this will help you

Happy Coding :)
enjoy it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];

for(int i=0;i<30;i++)

    {
      NSString str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i];
        if([array containsObject:str])
        {
          //do this
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Write this code :

```
NSMutableArray *arrCount = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20",@"21",@"22",@"23",@"24",@"25",@"26",@"27",@"28",@"29",@"30", nil];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"21",@"12",@"23",@"14",@"25", nil];

    for (NSString *strComapre in array)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",strComapre);
        if ([arrCount containsObject:strComapre]) 
        {
             NSLog(@"Compare");
        }
        else
        {
             NSLog(@"Not Compare");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an isEqualToArray method in NSArray. Can you not use that as follows:

`[array1 isEqualToArray:array2]`